# How can I make a Messenger App with IOS (Swift) and laravel backend? message not immediately

Tags: php, ios, swift, laravel, messenger

I have a messenger app in IOS (swift) with backend php laravel. 
It can be store message and send to others, but i have a trouble: when i send a message to my friends, my friends can't receive this message immediately, because I used post method, then if my friends want to get message, they must refresh app (or just call function get message), but, how do they now there is a message send to you(the app can't refresh continuity)???

How can i fix it?

I had searching framework to keep my message with id(to define message from ..., to ...), when I send a message to my friend, framework told to others who using this app know there is a message be sent, and with id, my friend can know like "this message send to you", then call function get message to get new message.
I had find some app can do it, but it using others backend: parse, firebase, syncano(so i can't use this). I think about push notification service in laravel, but i had 2 trouble with it:
- I used simulator to test app, so I can't get token to use push notification service (i not sure it work for me on real app).
- If using push notification service, then will be a notification send to user when setup first it, and I think it not good. 
Could someone help me out? or just I missing something. 
Thanks for read!

Comment: How about you store the message on the server if a client is offline, and when any of the client (iOS) is online, it'll query the server for new messages?

Comment: I use func viewDidLoad() for get all message for user (include new message). But with 2 users are already using app (it mean 2 users are online), how do they communicate together?

Comment: What do you think? Would relaying the message through the server be better or sending them directly between the users?

Comment: All message was stored in server. It mean if you are online and the other users send a message to you, how do you get new message through the server (without do nothing, not touching on app's interface)?

Comment: Your app periodically checks with the server whether you have new messages. You can look into things like `WebSocket`.

Comment: I will check it later, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. As a general tip for StackOverflow: If you ask more specific questions and present what you have tried already (small snippets of code), you are more likely to get help. For example, if you included a diagram of how your application communication looks like you would've gotten more answers. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for this! I just want to get framework or something for two or more users communicate together, and I have no idea for it. Any opinion will help me!

Comment: Why can't you use Syncano, Firebase, or Parse? What's the limitation preventing that?

Comment: Actually, Messenger just a function in my app. I've used Parse before but it so hard to manage relation table for remain function. Maybe I need use dedicated server for Messenger only. Thank you for your suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement push notifications. All chatting apps do this. Logic can be, when sender sends a message it should trigger a service (web service) and server should broad cast that push notification to all devices which are registered. Than on the receiver's end you need to verify if this message was meant for this receiver. <strike>For reference check out [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications). They have excellent documentation.</strike> 
Parse is shutting down, so it cant be used now.